# How can I make a router in PHP?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm currently developing a router for one of my projects and I need to do the following:

For example, imagine we have this array of set routes:

```
$routes = [
    'blog/posts' => 'Path/To/Module/Blog@posts',
    'blog/view/{params} => 'Path/To/Module/Blog@view',
    'api/blog/create/{params}' => 'Path/To/Module/API/Blog@create'
];
```

and then if we pass this URL through: `http://localhost/blog/posts` it will dispatch the `blog/posts` route - that's fine.

Now, when it comes to the routes that require parameters, all I need is a method of implementing the ability to pass the parameters through, (i.e. `http://localhost/blog/posts/param1/param2/param3` and the ability to prepend `api` to create `http://localhost/api/blog/create/` to target API calls but I'm stumped.

Comment: Dare I suggest you choose an existing router?

Comment: @Progrock I'd be happy to base it off of an existing router if it has similar functionality to what I need, but I'd prefer to build one that meets my criteria exactly if possible.

Comment: It's not clear what you want with a router, do you mean redirect? This is something you do on server (apache, nginx, etc) or you can use a slug as a primary key and whatever router as a value and save it on memcache. Later just query by current url and redirect.

Comment: Routing is a very generic task – what possible criteria you may have that is not implemented in, let's say, Symfony Routing? (available as separate package http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html)

Comment: I wish we could skip the usual "why don't you use a existing one" response, kind of redundant. Most likely everyone here knows there are existing routers. Some times people just want to make their own, for learning or just because, who cares. It just comes as condescending TBH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something basic, currently routes can have a pattern, and if the application paths start with that pattern then it's a match.  The rest of the path is turned into params.

```
<?php
class Route
{
    public $name;
    public $pattern;
    public $class;
    public $method;
    public $params;
}

class Router
{
    public $routes;

    public function __construct(array $routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function resolve($app_path)
    {
        $matched = false;
        foreach($this->routes as $route) {
            if(strpos($app_path, $route->pattern) === 0) {
                $matched = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(! $matched) throw new Exception('Could not match route.');

        $param_str = str_replace($route->pattern, '', $app_path);
        $params = explode('/', trim($param_str, '/'));
        $params = array_filter($params);

        $match = clone($route);
        $match->params = $params;

        return $match;
    }
}

class Controller
{
    public function action()
    {
        var_dump(func_get_args());
    }
}

$route = new Route;
$route->name    = 'blog-posts';
$route->pattern = '/blog/posts/';
$route->class   = 'Controller';
$route->method  = 'action';

$router = new Router(array($route));
$match  = $router->resolve('/blog/posts/foo/bar');

// Dispatch
if($match) {
    call_user_func_array(array(new $match->class, $match->method), $match->params);
}
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic version - simply just a concept version to show functionality and I wouldn't suggest using it in a production environment.

```
$routes = [
    'blog/view' => 'Example@index',
    'api/forum/create' => 'other.php'
];

$url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);

if (isset($url[0]))
{
    if ($url[0] == 'api')
    {
        $params = array_slice($url, 3);
        $url = array_slice($url, 0, 3);
    }
    else
    {
        $params = array_slice($url, 2);
        $url = array_slice($url, 0, 2);
    }
}

$url = implode('/', $url);

if (array_key_exists($url, $routes))
{
    $path = explode('/', $routes[$url]);
    unset($path[count($path)]);
    $segments = end($path);
    $segments = explode('@', $segments);

    $controller = $segments[0];
    $method = $segments[1];

    require_once APP_ROOT . '/app/' . $controller . '.php';
    $controller = new $controller;

    call_user_func_array([$controller, $method], $params);  
}
```